# Looping over an object to create bootstrap rows in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So consider the following:

```
renderCharacterSheetInfo() {
    let rows = [];
    let elements = [];
    let rowCount = 0;

    if (!this.state.loading) {

      const characterSheet = {
        strength: this.state.characterSheet.base_strength,
        dexterity: this.state.characterSheet.base_dexterity,
        agility: this.state.characterSheet.base_agility,
        intelligence: this.state.characterSheet.base_intelligence,
        health: this.state.characterSheet.base_health,
        gold: this.state.characterSheet.gold,
      };

      for(const key in characterSheet) {
        if (rowCount < 3) {
          elements.push(<div className="col-md-4" key={key}>{characterSheet[key]}</div>);
          rowCount++;
        } else {
          rows.push(elements);
          rowCount = 0;
          elements = [];
          elements.push(<div className="col-md-4" key={key}>{characterSheet[key]}</div>);
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(rows);
  }
```

What I am attempting to do is loop through the `characterSheet` object and create an array, `rows`, of arrays: `[[3 divs], [3 divs]]`.

Whats happening is, in the console, `[[3 divs]]` it loops though and creates the divs for the first three keys, but not the last three keys.

I am sure this is overly complicated, but Im not sure what to do here.

- **Expected:** `[[3 divs], [3 divs]]`
- **Actual:** `[[3 divs]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to split the rows into 3 divs each. A simpler way would be as shown and works even if there are more than six keys in future.

Basically you divide the index by 3 to get the first index and then push the items inside the nested array at that index.

ie, 
for keys 0,1,2 the index would be 0
for keys 3,4,5 the index would be 1 
and so on...

```
renderCharacterSheetInfo() {
    if (!this.state.loading) {
      const characterSheet = {
        strength: this.state.characterSheet.base_strength,
        dexterity: this.state.characterSheet.base_dexterity,
        agility: this.state.characterSheet.base_agility,
        intelligence: this.state.characterSheet.base_intelligence,
        health: this.state.characterSheet.base_health,
        gold: this.state.characterSheet.gold,
      };

      let rows = Object.keys(characterSheet).reduce((_rows,key,index) => {
        let rowIndex = Math.floor(index/3);
        if(!_rows[rowIndex]) {
            _rows[rowIndex] = []; //initialize with empty to push
        }

        _rows[rowIndex].push(<div className="col-md-4" key={key}>
 {characterSheet[key]} </div>)
        return _rows;
      },[]);

    console.log(rows);
  }
}
```